# C prog - Getting partial characters from an array element

Tags: c, loops, multidimensional-array, substring, c-strings

I have a code where I have obtained strings and put them in an array.

This array contains 10 elements/strings

```
MAY162019USA
AUG032021JAP
SEP032016ENG
(and 7 more strings like above)
```

What I need to do next is obtain the 5th to 8th character from the array above and run some if/else checks on it. So how do I reference these particulars characters within the array? I'd like to get the value like below from the array above.

```
2019
2021
2016
```

a[0] is MAY162019USA
a[1] is AUG032021JAP
ad so on

How to I reference particular characters from the array?

Comment: None of those strings will fit in a `char[10]`. Perhaps you meant `char *a[10]`?

Comment: @Mike Could you explain how can this array char a[10] accommodate the string MAY162019USA?

Comment: If the character at index `9` is never ever a digit just `strtol(input + 5, 0, 10)` (eg `strtol("MAY162019USA", 0, 10)` yields the `long` integer `2019`)

Comment: The "brute-force" way is, eg `1000*(a[0][5]-'0') + 100*(a[0][6]-'0') + 10*(a[0][7]-'0') + (a[0][8]-'0')`

Answer (score 0):

For starters this array

```
char a[10];
```

is not large enough to store for example the string "MAY162019USA".

Nevertheless according to your question it seems you need something like the following

```
char a[] = "MAY162019USA";

char value[5];

memcpy( value, a + 5, 4 );
value[4] = 0;

int num = ( int )strtol( value, NULL, 10 );
```

Now you can compare the integer 2019 with some other values.

Or if you have a two dimensional array like

```
char a[][13] =
{
    "AUG032021JAP", "SEP032016ENG"
};
```

then you can write

```
const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    char value[5];
    
    memcpy( value, a[i] + 5, 4 );
    value[4] = 0;

    int num = ( int )strtol( value, NULL, 10 );
    //...
}
```